# find the minimum sampling frequency at which the following signal must be sampled to avoid aliasing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sampling

find the minimum sampling frequency at which the following signal must be sampled to avoid aliasing

$x(t)=0.5+10\cos(2 \pi t)+20\sin(50 \pi t)$

my work

The frequency of the analogue signal can be calculated as

$2 \pi  F_1 = 2 \pi$

$F_1= 1$

$2 \pi F_2 = 50 \pi$

$F_2= 25$

then minimum is $1$

is that correct ???